# How can i change page by touching in android magazine app?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I will create a magazin app. In my app i want to change page by touching the page. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a **page curl effect**,Look at,

[Page Curl for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

[Android_page_curl by Harism](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this . [Page Curl Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/checkout)